# In my XAML can I make a ComboBox and multiple ComboBoxItems into a single Static or Dynamic Resource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have the following XAML snippet appearing multiple times in my XMAL file.
Is it possible to combine the ComboBox and ComboBoxItems into a single Static or Dynamic Resource to save room and simplify maintenance issues?

```
        <Button>
            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <ComboBox Width="34" FontSize="13" Margin="0" Padding="2,0,0,0">
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="01"></ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="02"></ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="03"></ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="04"></ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="05"></ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="06"></ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="08"></ComboBoxItem>
                    ....... ALL THE WAY TO 100 Items......                     
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="100"></ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
            </Canvas>    
        </Button>
```

Comment: **Solution: MVVM**. Create a proper ViewModel containing a `List<int> Numbers {get;set;}` and populate that by `Numbers = Enumerable.Range(0,100).ToList();` and then bind your UI to that, or create a style for ComboBoxes that sets the `ItemsSource` and `SelectedItem` properties accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

No need to declare so many comboboxItem's instances. Simply declare resource to provide ItemsSource to your comboBox (you can use **ObjectDataProvider**)

Declare this resource in UserControl, Window or App resource (wherever you feel like):

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="EnumerableRange"
                    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                    xmlns:linq="clr-namespace:System.Linq;assembly=System.Core"
                    ObjectType="{x:Type linq:Enumerable}" MethodName="Range">
     <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
         <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
         <sys:Int32>100</sys:Int32>
     </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
 </ObjectDataProvider>
```

you can use this for multiple comboboxes by setting ItemsSource like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EnumerableRange}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this part to your resource dictionary...

```
<Style x:Key="NumberComboButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="45"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1F3B53"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundAnimation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#F2FFFFFF"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#CCFFFFFF"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#7FFFFFFF"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#FF6DBDD1"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundAnimation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#D8FFFFFF"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#C6FFFFFF"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#8CFFFFFF"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" To="#3FFFFFFF"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To=".55"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="Background" CornerRadius="3" Background="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  Margin="1">
                            <Border Opacity="0"  x:Name="BackgroundAnimation" Background="#FF448DCA" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradient" >
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".7,0" EndPoint=".7,1">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <ComboBox Width="34" FontSize="13" Margin="0" Padding="2,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="01"></ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="02"></ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="03"></ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="04"></ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="05"></ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="06"></ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="08"></ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="100"></ComboBoxItem>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter
                          x:Name="contentPresenter"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" Margin="1" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and use it in your xaml like this..."

```
     <Button Style="{StaticResource NumberComboButton}"/>
```

I've edited this to provide the complete template instead of just the idea giver.

I removed your Canvas, because Canvases do not layout their children.

To make the button taller/wider you need to change the following properties:

```
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="45"/>

    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
```

Setting these values when specifying the Button in the XAML will overwrite the values specified in the style.

Finally, to change how the combo-box is aligned in your button, change the alignment in the combo-box - you can find the combo-box inside the button's grid (past the visual state manager stuff).

You can learn more here...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903963(v=vs.95).aspx - how to customize a button
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278069(v=vs.95).aspx - button template

Comment: This doean't work. The ComboBox replaces the whole button interior. I want a part of the button to remain, so I can click on the outside rim of the button, or click in the ComboBox itself.